# MacBook Pro OS X Yosemite having trouble dragging files using trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, trackpad

I used to drag files easily from one location to another in Finder on my old MacBook Pro with an older operating system. (using thumb and one finger on trackpad). Now I have to work really hard at it, and usually it opens the window i'm attempting to select, instead of letting me select and move it. After trying 4 or 5 times (and wearing out my arm muscles), I can get it. I'm sure there's a simpler way.

I tried to find preferences for this kind of thing, but under apple preferences, mouse, there is nothing (since I use a trackpad and not a mouse), and under trackpad it doesn't give choices for setting taps for dragging, or anything else related.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a hardware or software issue, do you think? Might be unrelated to your situation but I notice something similar to what you just described; when my RAM and/or CPU resources etc are stretched thin.

Comment: There is a three finger drag setting under System Preferences -> Trackpad, does that help you?

Comment: There is also a few other drag-related settings under System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Mouse & Trackpad (-> Trackpad Options). See also http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/46308/mac-os-x-maverick-re-enable-tap-and-drag-on-a-trackpad-or-touchpad/